# How to use AsyncElasticsearch client with FastAPI?

Tags: python, elasticsearch, asynchronous, web, fastapi

I have question that if my implementation was good enough and are there any better way to implement AsyncElastichsearc client with FastAPI in more controllable and esier to manage.

Current implementation.

I create a dependency in FastAPI to use AsyncElasticsearch

```
async def get_es():
    elastic_cred = get_elastic_cred()
    es = AsyncElasticsearch(**elastic_cred)
    try:
        yield es
    finally:
        await es.close()
```

I used this depenency in Fast API endpoint like below

```
@router.get("/chat/conversations")
async def get_conversations_api(
    req: ConversationsQueryParams = Depends(ConversationsQueryParams),
    user: User = Depends(get_user_info),
    db: PgDb = Depends(get_db),
    es: AsyncElasticsearch = Depends(get_es),
):
    pass
```

Then whenever API called, a new Elasticsearch connection will be created then being closed after API've done.

At this point, this make me feel like if there're some overhead time for creating ES connection and close this API's performance worse.

I have come up with other idea to use AsyncElasticsearch client as a singleton but I'm not sure that is it a proper way to handle AsyncElasticsearch connection because I didn
t find any recommendation from doc https://elasticsearch-py.readthedocs.io/en/v8.8.2/.

Please help me elaborate and which way is the best?